# How to add new child in Firebase database Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add a new child using the `DatabaseReference` in my `Firebase` Android app. I'm doing:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference() 
mDatabase.child("childToAdd").setValue(1);
```

I can do this with a regular `Firebase` Reference as it would add the child to the database if it isn't there.
How could I go about doing this with `DatabaseReference`?

Edit: Thanks for all the suggestions but I'm having issues with the following code. When it enters the if block it does not push the data onto the database.

https://gist.github.com/rounaksalim95/a5cba332400c6caf8320f15b0cbf06e8

When I try this with the old Firebase reference I get error code 11 (User code called from firebase runloop) and with the new database reference I get error code -3 (PermissionDenied even though I have no security rules).

Update:

I got it to do what I wanted to using a single value event listener:

```
Firebase userRef = new Firebase(BASEURL + "userData");

userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.child(user.getUid()).getValue() == null) {
            userRef.child(user.getUid()).setValue(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

However database reference doesn't let me add values like this.

Comment: I am sorry I may have misunderstood you question, but isn't `mDatabase` a `DatabaseReference`? The `getReference()` method returns `DatabaseReference`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You'll need to call `push()` to generate a unique key for the new data:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference() 
mDatabase.push().setValue(1);
```

This will append the new value at the end of the list.

By combining the `push()` and `child()` methods, you can create multiple lists of children in the database:

```
mDatabase.child("numbers").push().setValue(1);
mDatabase.child("numbers").push().setValue(53);
mDatabase.child("numbers").push().setValue(42);

mDatabase.child("letters").push().setValue("a");
mDatabase.child("letters").push().setValue("z");
mDatabase.child("letters").push().setValue("c");
```

See the section [append to a list of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data) in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, I have more issues with it since the transaction doesn't seem to be updating the value in the database (added edit to question).

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen How can I add nested child in firebase database?

Answer (score 3):

Another post mentioned to check your gradle app file to ensure you have the latest version of the Firebase as follows:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
```

I think this should fix many issues that could arise from using older versions.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add anything to the database if you're not authorized. You can do one of the following:

Either set this to your rules tab in firebase console:

```
{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true
}
}
```

Or you must create an authentication first (try with email/pass) and create user with

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

and then sign in with:

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

and you need to enable sign-in with email/pass in your console as well.

And then you can write data to your database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I have no authentication rules set up and the user is alright signed in; that's the user object I'm using in the block of code.

Comment: are you able to do it using push() ??

Comment: Or try mDatabase.child("childToAdd").setValue("1");

Comment: No, push isn't working either. I tried mDatabase.child("childToAdd").setValue(1); but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I tried using the single value event listener but I can read the value and if it is null then I try to add a child but that doesn't work either.

Comment: No with the "" in setvalue(). Look carefully. Setvalue("1") instead of setvalue(1).

Comment: It works with the single value event listener; I had an error in my check earlier. It works with 1 instead of "1"; shouldn't it work either way?

Comment: It works both ways. I just thought to try it out though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `push()` before set value in the firebase. It will create new user every time when you send value in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample, it may help you out.

```
     public class FirebaseUserDetails
    {
    private String mDisplayName;
    public String getmDisplayName() {
        return mDisplayName;
    }
public void setmDisplayName(String mDisplayName) {
    this.mDisplayName = mDisplayName;
}
}
```

Add your value to firebase database,

```
FirebaseUserDetails firebaseUserDetails = new FirebaseUserDetails();
firebaseUserDetails.setmDisplayName("arunwin");
DatabaseReference pathReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("contacts");
pathReference.child("arun").setValue(firebaseUserDetails).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

    }
});
```

And your result value will be added in your database like the below,

```
contacts:
    arun:
        mDisplayName:"arunwin"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i am adding new child like this!

**NOTE :** Here i am adding new child `refresh_token` to my `firebase database`

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("RegistrationModel").child(userId)
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Map<String, String> stringStringHashMap =(Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                    stringStringHashMap.put("refresh_token",refreshedToken);

                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("RegistrationModel").child(userId)
                            .setValue(stringStringHashMap);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```