# What happens when we refer to a child in firebase which doesn't exist?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I mean will it create a new child or will it throw an error?

Below are the code lines:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(id).child(marks);
```

The child name with the value "marks" doesn't exist in firebase

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access any child that is not exist in Firebase Database, it throws an error. And this code does not create any child this only use for getting a child that is really exist in FirebaseDatabase.
To create child follow this link:
[To create child follow this link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40013089/how-to-add-new-child-in-firebase-database-android)